# How to delete comma after the last element of the array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, xslt

My XML input is following:

```
<datafield tag="036F">
    <subfield code="n">Oxford University Press</subfield>
    <subfield code="n">1991-</subfield>
    </datafield>
```

I read it with XSLT and then send to Java:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$pica036F">
<xsl:variable name="codeN" select="./subfield[@code='n']" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$codeN">
    <xsl:variable name="codeBTemp" select="." />

    <xsl:value-of select="pica2dc:Pica036FNArray($codeBTemp)"></xsl:value-of>

</xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

And that's  my Java method that recieves $codeBTemp.
I makes the string from it and adds comma after every element.

```
 public static String Pica036FNArray(String codeBTemp) {
    String sb;
    sb = codeBTemp;
    setPica036FNArray(sb+",");
    return sb;
```

The concatanation of the strings is here:

```
public static void setPica036FNArray(String pica036fnArray) {
        pica036FNArray += pica036fnArray;
    }
```

As output I get:

Oxford University Press,1991-,Oxford University Press,1991-,

But it should look different (**no repeat and no last comma**) : 
Oxford University Press,1991-

Comment: Why aren't you doing it all in XSLT? And which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: I have XSLT 2.0. That's not my code. Just trying to fix it.  In XSLT I could get only the first "subfilef n" element

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, this is trivial: `<xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='n']" separator="," />`.

Answer (score 0):

"  Return sb.length > 0 ? Sb.substring(0,sb.length()-2));"
Apply last return line in this way...
Need to correct the syntax and will have to test with several types inputs.
Or maintain it in collection and use Java 8 stream api programming to use ',' as separator